# Custom database table design with Java and MS Access 

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, odbc, database-connection

While running the following code

```
public class Temp {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Connection con; // The connection to the database.
        // The following code can throw errors, so they must be caught.
        try{

            // First, tell Java what driver to use and where to find it.
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            // Next, create a connection to your data source.
            // Specify that you are using the ODBC-JDBC Bridge.
            // And specify the data source from ODBC.
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Temp");
            // Create an SQL statement.
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            // Execute some SQL to create a table in your database.
            // If the table already exists, an exception is thrown!
            stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE COFFEES " +
            "(COF_NAME VARCHAR(32), SUP_ID INTEGER, PRICE FLOAT, " +
            "SALES INTEGER, TOTAL INTEGER)");

        }
        // Catch any exceptions that are thrown.
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e){

            System.out.println(e.toString());

        }
        catch(SQLException e){

            System.out.println(e.toString());

        }

    }

}
```

i got the error as

> java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Cannot modify the design of table 'COFFEES'.  It is in a read-only database.

please help

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have write access to the database/file with your current user.

Comment: i didn't created the database

Comment: Do a right click on it and make sure that you have write permissions to the file.

Comment: I checked file permissions and gave the Windows user Full Control and Ownership over the database file.  Additionally, there is no user security in the Access file itself.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `"ReadOnly=False;"` to your connection string

Comment: I added `Mode=ReadWrite;ReadOnly=false` to the connection string... it still didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Check the advanced options in the ODBC DSN and make sure `ReadOnly` is set to `0`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try deleting the table explicitly and run again.

Comment: i didn't created the database

Comment: I have a slightly different statement than the OP.  My statement is `DROP TABLE MyTest`.  Access is not installed on the server so opening the GUI is not an option.